# Генерировать программный код во время исполнения программы

Tags: java, трансляция, транслятор

У меня есть импровизированный язык программирования, в котором есть логические выражения. Эти логические выражения довольно похожи на логические выражения в Java. Мне бы очень не хотелось описывать парсер выражений, дерево выражений и его обход для оценки истиности. Вместо этого хотелось бы транслировать выражение из этого языка в обычное логическое выражение на Java и передать на оценку JVM.
Как внутри программы на Java сгенерировать из входной строки логическое выражение, которое потом можно было бы проверить на истиность?
Да, я понимаю, что для безопасности надо будет написать фильтр для входного выражения.

Comment: по описанию очень похоже на то, что делает паттерн, называемый интерпретатор

Comment: @Дмитрий Действительно похоже, спасибо

Comment: не за что, пользуйтесь)

Comment: @Дмитрий только я вот не соображу, неужели придется описывать все возможные входные конструкции? все-таки у меня планируются и обращения к переменным для их сравнения

Comment: нет, почитайте про указанный паттерн больше и посмотрите примеры. то, о чем вы говорите, это кодирование путем исключения и это не паттерн, а антипаттерн)